# Append pageName and record Id to Network.communitiesLanding()

Tags: apex, community, network

I have created a class for Slack Notification and I would link to create a link to view the Question Post created on community.
The link should take me the the question post as seen below:

User-added image

[image]

I am using a network class "communitiesLanding()" but I am unable to append the PageName and record.Id the Network.communitiesLanding().

[image]

How can I append the pageName and record.Id to create this link
https://testcase-smartadserver.cs89.force.com/support/s/question/0D50E00000Made1SAB

```
    public class SlackNotificationCommunityPost {
    
    /*
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- - Description   : Class to send Slack notification based on QuestionPost created on Community
    -- -----------  ----  -------  ------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    
    public class slackRequest {
        @InvocableVariable(label='title')
        public String title; 
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='id')
        public String id; 
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='name')
        public String name;    
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Publish New Community posts to Slack')
    public static void publishNewCommunityPostsToSlack(List<slackRequest> requests) {

        //String webhookURL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/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';
        String webhookURL = system.label.Param_Slack_Token;
        String msg;
        String channelName;
        
        Network myNetwork = [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name ='Smart Client Portal'];
        System.debug('MyDebug: ' +Network.communitiesLanding());
        String fullRecordURL = Network.communitiesLanding() + 'question/';
        

        for(slackRequest r:requests){
            
            if(r.id != null && r.name != null && r.title != null) {
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationCommunityPosts new post');
                channelName = '#' +Label.Slack_Community_Channel;
                msg = 'A new community post has been created : *'+r.title+'* - By User : (*'+r.name+'*)';
                msg += '\nLink to Community post : '+fullRecordURL+'/'+r.id;
            }
            
            //Generate JSON for request
            try {
                if (r.id != null && r.title !=null && r.name != null) {
                   System.debug('### SlackNotificationCommunityPosts sending message');
                   JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
                    gen.writeStartObject(); //Inserts {
                    gen.writeStringField('text', msg);
                    gen.writeStringField('channel', '#salesforce_test');
                    gen.writeStringField('username', 'bot-support');
                    gen.writeStringField('icon_emoji', ':smartplus:');
                    gen.writeEndObject(); //Inserts }
                    String body = gen.getAsString(); //Translates JSONGenerator to string to be passed to callout
                    System.debug('### SlackNotificationCommunityPosts body: '+ body);
                    System.enqueueJob(new qCallOut(webhookURL, 'POST', body)); // Send request
      
                 } else {
                    System.debug('### SlackNotificationCommunityPosts Id = '+ r.id);
                    return; 
                }
                
            }
            catch (exception e) {
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationCommunityPosts error:' +e);
            }
            
        }
     
    }
    
     public class qCallOut implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
         
        private final String url;
        private final String method;
        private final String body;
         
        public qCallOut(String url, String method, String body) {
            this.url = url;
            this.method = method;
            this.body = body;
        }
         
        public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(url);
            req.setMethod(method);
            req.setBody(body);
            Http http = new Http();
            // to pass when process builder is invoked by another test class
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){  
              HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            }
        }
         
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to find how to append pageName and a specific record to Network class
communitiesLanding().

You need to use getUrl() + PageName + record.Id:
msg += '\nLink to Community post : '+Network.communitiesLanding().getUrl()+'question/'+r.id;

```
  //String webhookURL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/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';
    String webhookURL = system.label.Param_Slack_Token;
    String msg;
    String channelName;
    
    for(slackRequest r:requests){
        
        if(r.id != null && r.name != null && r.title != null) {
            System.debug('### SlackNotificationCommunityPosts new post');
            channelName = '#' +Label.Slack_Community_Channel;
            msg = 'A new community post has been created : *'+r.title+'* - By User : (*'+r.name+'*)';
            msg += '\nLink to Community post : '+Network.communitiesLanding().getUrl()+'question/'+r.id;
        }
```